# Difference between "drink" and "beverage"

Tags: difference

Is there any difference between the words "drink" and "beverage"? The internet is not consistent enough about the definitions. I found all of the following (list not exhaustive):

- they are the same;
- "beverage" does NOT refer to water, but to anything else safe for drinking;
- "beverage" is made to be sold.

Side question: Can I order a "beverage"? I never encountered a question like: "What beverage would you like?"

I already know that ordering "drinks" is a common thing.

Comment: They are the same, but 'beverage' is more formal (it comes from the Latin via this route: : Latin _bibere_ ‘to drink’ -> Old French _bevrage_ -> Middle English _beverage_. You can say 'Can I order a beverage' perhaps in a café, but many people would think that was oddly formal and kind of bookish. Water can definitely be called a beverage.

Comment: As drink generally conveys a sense of pleasure, "beverage" will be used in others cases, e.g. *After surgery, no food or beverage are allowed in the recovery room*.

Comment: @Graffito - are you sure about that? As a general rule?

Comment: I've had this conversation many times with a room full of native speakers. I'm surprised you didn't also come across opinions on whether a "beverage" must, can, or cannot contain alcohol. You're not likely to get a definitive answer here.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: It's of course not a general rule, but it provides a reason for selecting one of the 2 synonyms.

Comment: You can *drink*, but you can't *beverage*. BTW, one certainly may hear, "What is the beverage of your choice," in a restaurant or bar, and I sincerely believe that the server is asking about something *pleasurable* you'd *like* to imbibe.

Comment: @gotube: I am usually in rooms full of non-native speakers. If you assumption would stand (that we all can have easy access to native speakers), then the entire ELL would be useless.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: the words are "drink" and "beverage", and NOT "to drink" and "to beverage". Additionally, I am not a vegetable or a sponge, and therefore I do not *imbibe*.

Comment: @virolino - imbibe 1. to consume (liquids) by drinking; drink. _He imbibed great quantities of iced tea_

Comment: @virolino You've misunderstood. I meant to tell you that even native speakers don't agree on precisely what "beverage" and "drink" mean, so I'm not surprised dictionaries you've checked don't give clear answers.

Comment: @gotube: oh! In that case, we agree :)

Comment: @Graffito I think beverage is seen as more formal and therefore perhaps more appropriate in a clinical context, but "no food or drink" is just as likely a prohibition after surgery.  Some might prefer "beverage" to avoid people thinking that "drink" refers only to alcohol; others might prefer "drink" if there are a lot of immigrants or tourists who might be less likely to understand "beverage."

Answer (score 1):

"drink" and "beverage" are approximately the same if you consider the meaning of "drink" which matches up with "beverage". However there are nuances.

- The word "drink" has Germanic origins and happens to be *much more common* in everyday usage than "beverage", of French origins. That's a pattern in English, where the French word sounds more literary or advanced, but basic nouns and verbs (cook, eat, drink, walk, run, sleep) are Old English.
- "Have a drink", in the context of bar or pub, would strongly imply alcohol. "Have a beverage" * would not be idiomatic. And might or might not imply alcohol.
- "Take a drink", when any liquid is present, means to imbibe.  "Take a beverage" * would not be correct.
- Does "beverage" refer to water? It usually excludes water, and implies something other than water, but not in a strict way.  If someone asked if you'd like a beverage, water would still be an acceptable answer.
- Are beverages made to be sold? That's not their definition, no. If a beverage is "a drink, usually other than water" including coffee, tea, juice, etc. then *coincidentally* in modern society those are all consumer products made to be sold.
- Can I order a "beverage"? Yes. It might sound overly formal.

Comment: "would not be idiomatic": it would be idiomatic if the speaker is being humorous or otherwise affecting an air of mock formality, etc.  Also, it seems as though "have a drink" implies alcohol in most contexts; "have something to drink" is more neutral.  This is at least true in the northeastern US, where I grew up.  When I moved to Europe I needed to adjust a bit to people (non-native speakers of English) ordering coffee or a soft drink after saying "let's have a drink."

Comment: Also I would note that "take a drink" is typically employing a different sense of "drink" that _isn't_ synonymous with "beverage" because it refers to the act of drinking, similar to "take a sip" and analogous to "take a bite."